# Copy file to a folder with write permission only

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy the file to a specific folder and the user has the write permission only to that folder.

here is the code I am using and it is giving me  (access to the path is denied) error.

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:");
                FileInfo[] fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles($"abc_Converted.txt");
                foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfos)
                {
                    File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine($"D:\\D", file.Name), true);  // overwrites existing
                }
```

[image: Code screenshot]
any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Here is my folder permission
[image]

Comment: Can you show the permissions too?

Comment: yup, I will update my question.

Comment: @CaiusJard already updated my question thank you :)

Comment: May I suggest you enable all permissions, see if it works, then work backwards towards what you posted, seeing at what point it stops? Also, is the app certainly running as this user?

Comment: @CaiusJard the program works when I enable the full control but then when I remove the read permission that is when the error comes out. yup the app is running with this user.

Comment: It would thus appear that a Copy does a Read for some reason.. You can read through the code of System.IO.File [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4a0905e7dc32d77d)

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you for your help. after reading the system.IO. I came across the Move function which does not use read permission and it did work for me.

Comment: After reading that source code.. if the Copy does a read on the destination, it must be happening in the underlying win32 call (which I doubt).  I would bet that there is something else happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have write permissions.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Write access to the contents of the file or access to change information about the file, such as its name. Also allows for deletion and overwriting.

You are copying a file, so its a create.

Comment: This answer seems to be missing some words ?